# Batch file creation to execute POST method in Flask API (windows)

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, flask

I've to create a batch file so that it calls the following API POST method and executes it seamlessly on Windows. There is no input that is required to be provided to the POST method here

this is for a ML module which is being called by the API. I've tried calling the mentioned module directly through batch file and anaconda prompt but that doesn't work fine.

```
import CLassName1
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/model/testing', methods=['POST'])
def test_model():
     response=ClassName1.method_name1()
     return response

@app.route('/test')
def post_health():
     return "health"

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=15010, debug=True)
```

expected to run method_name1 and subsequent methods and then populate another file- 'Output' created in the parent folder.

actually- when method_name1 is executed directly from anaconda prompt throws an Import error after some time and keeps looping over

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the exact error stack trace that you are getting when you calls method_name1() because as long as method_name1() returns string or there is no error in method_name1(), this code should run.

Comment: I'm unable to provide the stack trace due to some privacy issues but when I make a call through the API then everything works fine; which means that the function is not having any errors.
The only thing is I wanted to know how to call a POST method API from a batch file (the POST method here doesn't require any input)
Any help by you would be beneficial